# Extracting string array from SSIS variable

Tags: ssis, arrays, script-task

I have two script tasks in my SSIS package.  The first one saves a string array as a package variable:

```
// In 1st script task:
String[] astrCustNames = new String[cust_count];

/* ...
 * Some code to add strings to array ...
 */

// Add array to a package variable
Dts.Variables["CustomerNames"].Value = astrCustNames;
```

The second task should then extract the strings from the variable.  In the past, I've done this with a table variable.  This won't work for the string array:

```
// In 2nd script task:
OleDbDataAdapter ole_da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
// Fill the customer names data table
DataTable dtCustNames = new DataTable();
ole_da.Fill(dtCustNames, Dts.Variables["User::CustomerNames"].Value);
```

The call that fills the data adapter will result in the error "Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record."

The .dtsx package lists the data type as DTS:DataType="13"

The data type of the variable as it is defined in the package is "Object":

```
// Returns type "Object":
TypeCode cur_type = Dts.Variables["User::CustomerNames"].DataType;
```

I've been searching for an example of extracting strings stored in an array in an SSIS variable, but have found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that this couldn't be simpler.

Just cast the value to a string array:

```
String[] astrCustNames = (String[])Dts.Variables["User::CustomerNames"].Value;
```